# kubernetes-dashboard CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I deployed Kubernetes cluster with Ansible and kuberspay

Noone task get "fail" status on my cluster.

But my Dashborad pod get errors

Then i tryed to open my UI dashboard.

But I cant get access to Kubernetes Daschboard:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403
}
```

network:

```
ens192: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.2.67.201  netmask 255.0.0.0  broadcast 10.255.255.255
        ether 00:50:56:9c:0e:b0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7564605  bytes 6551785783 (6.1 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2925952  bytes 4385152422 (4.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 51783307  bytes 11498086915 (10.7 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 51783307  bytes 11498086915 (10.7 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tunl0: flags=193<UP,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1440
        inet 10.233.70.0  netmask 255.255.255.255
        tunnel   txqueuelen 1000  (IPIP Tunnel)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Inventory file:

```
master ansible_host=10.2.67.201 ansible_user=root
worker1 ansible_host=10.2.67.203 ansible_user=root
worker2 ansible_host=10.2.67.205 ansible_user=root
worker3 ansible_host=10.2.67.206 ansible_user=root
#[all:vars]
#ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3

[kube-master]
master

[kube-node]
worker1
worker2
worker3

[etcd]
master

[calico-rr]

[k8s-cluster:children]
kube-master
kube-node
calico-rr
```

kubectl get pods -n kube-system:

```
NAME                                       READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-6d57b44787-xlj89   1/1     Running             13         5d23h
calico-node-dwm47                          0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    74         5h33m
calico-node-hhgzk                          1/1     Running             12         5d23h
calico-node-tk4mp                          0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    75         5h33m
calico-node-w7zvs                          0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    75         5h33m
coredns-74c9d4d795-xpbsd                   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          5h32m
dns-autoscaler-7d95989447-7kqsn            1/1     Running             7          5d23h
kube-apiserver-master                      1/1     Running             0          5d23h
kube-controller-manager-master             1/1     Running             0          5d23h
kube-proxy-9bt8m                           1/1     Running             0          5h33m
kube-proxy-cbrcl                           1/1     Running             0          5h33m
kube-proxy-stj5g                           1/1     Running             0          5h33m
kube-proxy-zql86                           1/1     Running             0          5h33m
kube-scheduler-master                      1/1     Running             0          5d23h
kubernetes-dashboard-7c547b4c64-6skc7      0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    367        5d23h
nginx-proxy-worker1                        1/1     Running             0          5h33m
nginx-proxy-worker2                        1/1     Running             0          5h33m
nginx-proxy-worker3                        1/1     Running             0          5h33m
nodelocaldns-6t92x                         1/1     Running             0          5h33m
nodelocaldns-kgm4t                         1/1     Running             0          5h33m
nodelocaldns-xl8zg                         1/1     Running             0          5h33m
nodelocaldns-xwlwk                         1/1     Running             9          5d23h
```

Some Problem Pod's Logs:

```
kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-7c547b4c64-6skc7 --namespace=kube-system
2019/09/18 14:45:09 Starting overwatch
2019/09/18 14:45:09 Using in-cluster config to connect to apiserver
2019/09/18 14:45:09 Using service account token for csrf signing
2019/09/18 14:45:10 Error while initializing connection to Kubernetes apiserver. This most likely means that the cluster is misconfigured (e.g., it has invalid apiserver certificates or service account's configuration) or the --apiserver-host param points to a server that does not exist. Reason: Get https://10.233.0.1:443/version: dial tcp 10.233.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
Refer to our FAQ and wiki pages for more information: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/FAQ
```

So I cant open my Dashboard.

Logs from another failed pods: **calico-node-dwm47, calico-node-tk4mp, calico-node-w7zvs**

```
2019-09-19 06:48:26.023 [INFO][8] startup.go 256: Early log level set to info
2019-09-19 06:48:26.024 [INFO][8] startup.go 272: Using NODENAME environment for node name
2019-09-19 06:48:26.024 [INFO][8] startup.go 284: Determined node name: worker3
Calico node failed to start
ERROR: Error accessing the Calico datastore: dial tcp 10.2.67.201:2379: connect: no route to host[
```

core-dns:

```
 kubectl logs coredns-74c9d4d795-xpbsd   --namespace=kube-system
```

Error from server (BadRequest): container "coredns" in pod "coredns-74c9d4d795-xpbsd" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating

Comment: Seems like there is a network issue, you may need to take a look at why calico node failed to start first.

Comment: Please provide output of description from all pods with `CrashLoopBackOff` : `kubectl describe pod calico-node-dwm47 -n kube-system` also provide output of `kubectl describe pod coredns-74c9d4d795-xpbsd -n kube-system`

Comment: hey guys! thx for feedback! I added logs that u ask

Comment: Are you are using `Kubeadm` or your cluster is in cloud?

Comment: I use baremetal

Comment: It's trying to connect the apiserver at `10.233.0.1:443` are you sure it's running there?